# how to make a transaction code automatically by date in java?

Tags: java, mysql

I'm confused how to create based on the date the transaction code in java and mysql, help me.

Comment: I'm confused about what do you need

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: whats a transaction code

Comment: before asking please try something.

Comment: you want to do some work in java based on date Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to get the Date value from System.
There is some way to get it :

Get Date in Java
Filed under: Java, Programming — Leave a comment
30 November 2011

I’ll give you 2 example.

Example 1:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(df.format(cal.getTime()));

Or youcan use Date instead of Calendar, like this:

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date dt = new Date();
System.out.println(sdf.format(dt));
```

You can manipulate the Date Format.

And after that you can manipulate that value to somehing like your transcation code you want. 
Like

```
Int index = 0

String transcode;

transcode = sdf &index

index +=1
```

just be more creative.